# After twaillio call required condition is false: format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate'

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioengine, sample-rate

This is working fine until I make a call using a twillo framework and again start listening. it is crashing with the following error

required condition is false: `format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate'`

it is crashing on this line

```
inputNode?.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) {[weak self] (buffer, when) in
            self?.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
        }
```

Here is the full code

```
class MySppechRecognizer: NSObject,SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate {
    /// initalize the speech recognitior . it is a shared instace.
    static let speechSharedInstance = MySppechRecognizer()
    var isSppechRecognisationAvaible = true
    var speechRecognizer:SFSpeechRecognizer? = nil
    var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    var recognitionTask: SFSpeechRecognitionTask?
    var recognitionRequest: SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest?
    var isFinalWord = false
    var inputNode:AVAudioInputNode? = nil
    var callBack:jimboSpeechCallBack? = nil
    var isHotWordDetectedForApp = false

    func setSpeechRec() {
        if speechRecognizer == nil {
            speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: kAppLocal)
            speechRecognizer?.delegate = self
        }
    }


}

    //MARK:- Delegate
    func speechRecognizer(_ speechRecognizer: SFSpeechRecognizer, availabilityDidChange available: Bool) {
        print("Availibility changes")            
    }
    //MARK:- Audio engine
    func startRecording(){
   if recognitionTask != nil {
            self.recognitionRequest?.endAudio()
            recognitionTask?.cancel()
            recognitionTask = nil
            recognitionRequest = nil
            inputNode?.reset()
            inputNode?.removeTap(onBus: 0)
            inputNode?.reset()
            stopRecording()
        }

        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: .measurement)
            try audioSession.setMode(.measurement)
            try audioSession.setPreferredSampleRate(44100)
            try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        } catch {
            print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")
        }
        inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
        recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
        recognitionRequest?.shouldReportPartialResults = true
        recognitionTask =  MySppechRecognizer.speechSharedInstance.speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest!, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
            print("Result is===\(String(describing: result?.bestTranscription.formattedString))")
            var isFinal = false
            if result != nil {
                isFinal = (result?.isFinal)!
                self.isFinalWord = (result?.isFinal)!
            }
            if error != nil || isFinal {
                self.audioEngine.stop()
                self.inputNode?.removeTap(onBus: 0)
                self.recognitionRequest = nil
                self.recognitionTask = nil
            }
            if error != nil {
                print(“Error === \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                self.isFinalWord = true
            }
            guard self.callBack == nil else {
                self.callBack!(result,error)
                return
            }
        })

        let recordingFormat = inputNode?.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
        inputNode?.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) {[weak self] (buffer, when) in
            self?.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
        }
        audioEngine.prepare()
        do {
            try audioEngine.start()
        } catch {
            print("audioEngine couldn't start because of an error.")
        }
    }

    /// to stop the audio session
    func stopRecording() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if ((self.audioEngine.isRunning)){
                    self.recognitionRequest?.endAudio()
                self.recognitionTask?.cancel()
                self.recognitionTask = nil
                self.recognitionRequest = nil
                self.inputNode?.reset()
                self.inputNode?.removeTap(onBus: 0)
                self.inputNode?.reset()
                self.audioEngine.inputNode.reset()
            }
        }
    }
}
```